# Why does SQLInstallDriverEx succeed without admin privileges?

Tags: windows, odbc

I have a program installing an ODBC driver. I want to check if the user has sufficient permissions to run it, but want to avoid checking registry entry permissions.

Driver installation implies adding entry for it in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ODBC/ODBCINST.INI` registry key. If I install the driver as admin everything is perfect. If I do not have admin privileges I expect the `SQLInstallDriverEx` call to fail as I do not have permissions for the mentioned registry keys. However `SQLInstallDriverEx` succeeds, but `SQLGetInstalledDrivers` won't return the installed driver in the list. `SQLRemoveDriver` also succeeds with the usage count corresponding to number of times I called `SQLInstallDriverEx` as non-admin.

What happens here? Where is the installed driver info stored in this case?

Thank you

Comment: Only the functions succeed, the driver is not really installed, it cannot be seen in ODBC Data Source Administrator or the registry.

Comment: I believe the technical term for this would be "Windows bug".  There's no discussion of Admin privileges in the documentation of [`SQLInstallDriverEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlinstalldriverex-function).